# Search and erase db rows with file checker

Tags: php, mysql, database, file, erase

Hi I am trying to get a file path from the embed field, use that path to see if a file exists in that path. If the file dose not exist then delete that entry. I am running a game site and the script that downloads the game file skipped a few so its like finding a needle in a 4000 entry db haystack. Any help is appreciated. Here is my code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['clean'])) {
$query = "SELECT * FROM games WHERE embed";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die ("no query");

$result_array_path = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $result_array_path = $row;
}
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);
for($counter=0;$counter<$count;$counter++){
if (file_exists($result_array_path[$counter])){

}else{
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM games WHERE embed".$result_array_path[$counter]);
    echo $result_array_path[$counter]." ";
}
}
}
?>
```

--------------EDIT-------------

I Updated the code to BUT it decides to delete my entire database instead  of deleting the missing game entries. Here is the revised code:

```
    <?php
if(isset($_POST['clean'])) {
$query = "SELECT * FROM games WHERE embed NOT LIKE '%mochiads.com%'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die ("no query");

$result_array_path = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $result_array_path[] = $row['embed'];
}
foreach($result_array_path as $path) {
  if(!file_exists($path)) {
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM games WHERE embed = '" . $path . "'");
    echo $path." | ";
  }
}
}
?>
```

-----------EDIT--------------

I debugged the program so it works now. Had to add a "`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`" to the program. Here is the finished program

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['clean'])) {
$query = "SELECT * FROM games WHERE embed NOT LIKE '%mochiads.com%'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die ("no query");

$result_array_path = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $result_array_path[] = $row['embed'];
}
 foreach($result_array_path as $path) {
      $rel_path = str_replace('http://www.flamegame.net', '', $path);
      $rel_path = str_replace('http://flamegame.net', '', $rel_path);
      $rel_path = str_replace('%20', ' ', $rel_path);

      if(! file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $rel_path)) {
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM games WHERE embed = '" . $path . "'");
    echo $rel_path." | ";
  }
}
}
?>
```

Thanks For all of the help Especially Gargron.

For those who are wondering this program is for my website:
http://www.FlameGame.net

Comment: What's the output that you get?

Comment: nothing - the page simply reloads no output

Answer (score 0):

I see one typo that might be your problem:

```
$result_array_path = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
  // You want to append the row to the results array
  // instead of replacing the array each time, so []
  $result_array_path[] = $row['embed'];
  // That's assuming the table field containing the path is "embed"
}
```

And instead of using `mysql_num_rows` you could instead iterate through the items in `$result_array_path` like this:

```
foreach($result_array_path as $path) {
  if(! file_exists($path)) {
    // Delete
    // You missed a = in the query too
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM games WHERE embed = '" . $path . "'");
  }
}
```

That should make it work.

Comment: I implemented code and I am getting an error

Warning: file_exists() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: @user2030325 Oh, I'm sorry, right. `$row` is an array of the fields from the database. You should use $row['embed'] probably, editing the answer now.

Comment: I ran the program - no errors but it decided to delete everything in my database instead of deleting what I wanted to delete. Some minor inconvenience rebuilding the database.